# java.lang.ClassCastException: ItemAttachment cannot be cast to FileAttachment

Tags: java, exchangewebservices

can anyone help on the below issue in EWS,

I am getting an error java.lang.ClassCastException: microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.property.complex.ItemAttachment cannot be cast to microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.property.complex.FileAttachment

```
    private static void readAttachment(ExchangeService service, Folder folder, int n) {
    ItemView view = new ItemView(n);
    FindItemsResults<Item> findResults;
    try {
    findResults = service.findItems(folder.getId(), view);
    System.out.println("findResults-->"+findResults.getTotalCount());


    for (Item item : findResults) {
        EmailMessage email;

            email = EmailMessage.bind(service, item.getId(), new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly, ItemSchema.Attachments));
            System.out.println("email.getAttachments().getCount()-->"+email.getAttachments().getCount());
            //email.load();
            for (Attachment it : email.getAttachments()) {
                System.out.println(it.getName());
                FileAttachment iAttachment = (FileAttachment) it;
                //iAttachment.load( "C:\\FileLocation\\" + iAttachment .getName());
            }

    }
    } catch (ServiceLocalException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about which part of the error message is confusing you? Can you let us know what you have tried in order to fix it after doing some research on that exception?

Comment: getting the above casting exception in this line FileAttachment iAttachment = (FileAttachment) it;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `FileAttachment` and `ItemAttachment` are direct subclasses of `Attachment` class. It seams some of the attachments are instance of `ItemAttachment` and you are trying to cast them to `FileAttachment`. Since `FileAttachment` class is not a subclass of `ItemAttachment` you cannot cast to it.

With an example:

```
public class Animal {  }
public class Dog extends Animal { }
public class Cat extends Animal { }

Animal a = new Dog();
Cat c = (Cat)a; // this line produces ClassCastException as in your case
```

in this example you cannot

Comment: Thank you! I removed one ItemAttachment in mail box. after that it worked perfectly.